# Equivariant maps are closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X= \mathbb{A}_K^2 \setminus \{0\}$ with a $K^*$ action given by $c.(x, y)= (cx, cy)$ and $Y= \mathbb{A}_K^2 \setminus \{0\}$ with $K^*$ action given by $c.(x, y) =( c^{d_1}x, c^{d_2}y)$ for some positive integers $d_1$ and $d_2$. Let $f: X \to Y $ be a $K^*$ eqivariant map.

Question: Is $f$ closed ?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890057/morphism-of-varieties-is-closed).

Comment: In the question you reffered, $X$ was assumed to be complete, which is not in our case.

Comment: I think one can argue:If you quotient by the action of $\mathbb{G}_m$, you get $\mathbb{P}^1 \to M= Y/\mathbb{G}_m$, where the second one is a proper stack (it has stabilizers that are subgroups of the n roots of unity, where n is the gcd of $d_1$ and $d_2$). In particular $\mathbb{P}^1 \to M$ is proper, because $\mathbb{P}^1$ is proper and $M$ is a separated stack.The morphism $X \to Y$ is a morphism of $G_m$-bundles over the morphism $\mathbb{P}^1 \to M$. In particular $X \to Y$ is the base change of $\mathbb{P}^1 \to M$ using $Y \to M$. Since $\mathbb{P}^1 \to M$ is proper, so is $X \to Y$.

Comment: I think $X \to Y$ can not be the base change of $\mathbb{P}^1 \to M$ using $Y \to M$. For example consider the map $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ defined by $(x, y) \to (x^2, y^2)$. Let $Z$ be a one point scheme $\{x\}$. Define maps from $Z \to \mathbb{P}^1$ by $x \to [1,1]$ and $Z \to Y$ by $x \to (1,1)$. Then these maps makes diagram commutative but there are two maps from $Z \to X$ namely, $x \to (1, 1)$ and $x \to (-1, -1)$ making the fiber product diagram commutative, which violates the universal property of fiber product. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LAPRAS The thing is that you need to be careful when taking a fiber product when stacks are involved. In this case I am assuming that you are taking the action on $Y$ with $d_1=d_2=2$. In this case $M = Y/\mathbb{G}_m$ is the stack $\mathbb{P}^1 \times B\mu_2$. The $Z$-points of the fiber product $X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times_{M} Y$ correspond to points $f \in \mathbb{P}^1(Z)$ and $g \in Y(Z)$ along with an isomorphism of the compositions to $Z \to M$. In this case there are two possible choices of isomorphism (the two elements of $\mu_2$), which is why you get two different points in $X$.

Comment: (Recall that the morphisms $Z \to M$ form a groupoid, not a set. You need to keep track of isomorphisms).